# compiling php and its dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, php, dependencies

I'm trying to compile php from source on ubuntu 13.04 but I'm struggling to find what dependencies i need to install using apt-get to get it to compile.

Whats the easiest why to find what i need to install going by the configure command? for eg i used ./configure --help

and came up this with this but that does not give much insite into what dependencies that need to be installed

```
--enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --enable-opcache --with-openssl --with-curl=/usr/bin --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-intl --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr 
--with-freetype-dir=/usr --enable-intl --enable-mbstring 
--with-mcrypt=/usr --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvshm --enable-zip --with-pear
```

Comment: Why are you doing this at all?!

Comment: Because the application that's been deployed does not support the old version that's in the ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy why when running ./configure it slowly told me one by one what lib i needed to install.